# Replace TrueType(CID) encoded Identity-H string in pdf with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

My task consist to replace a string in a pdf.
Unfortunately, that string is TrueType CID fonts encoded with Identity-H.

This is  the cos dictionary:

```
(COSName{Font}:COSDictionary{(COSName{F1}:COSDictionary{(COSName{DescendantFonts}:COSArray{[COSObject{32, 0}]})COSName{BaseFont}:COSName{RVJLXS+ArialUnicodeMS})(COSName{Type}:COSName{Font}) (COSName{Encoding}:COSName{Identity-H})COSName{Subtype}:COSName{Type0})COSName{ToUnicode}:COSDictionary{(COSName{Length}:COSInt{647})(COSName{Filter}:COSName{FlateDecode}) }) })
```

Indeed, when I extract the string's token it appears with ascii characters like this:"$ O H V V D Q G U R"
To decode it I use the following code:

```
COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
 byte[] String_byte = previous.getString().getBytes();
String_byte = previous.getString().getBytes();
codeLength = 1;
for (int in = 0; in < String_byte.length; in += codeLength) {
// Decode the value to a
// Unicode
// character
codeLength = 1;
String c = Font_Type.encode(String_byte, in, codeLength);
int[] codePoints = null;
if (c == null && in + 1 < String_byte.length) {
// maybe a multibyte
// encoding
codeLength++;
c = Font_Type.encode(String_byte, in, codeLength);
codePoints = new int[] { Font_Type.getCodeFromArray(String_byte,in, codeLength) };
}
```

that works fine. After the decoding, I replace the string obtained but I'm not able to encode it again in order to obtain the right ascii sequence, like the previous ($ O H V V D Q G U R), to replace or append in the original one.

```
previous.append(newstring.getBytes());
```

I hope it is all clear.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Ale

Comment: Is the font in question embedded in the PDF? In that case, have you checked whether the characters you want to use in your replacement exist in the font embedded in the PDF at all? Often merely a subset of a font is embedded, the subset of the glyphs which actually are use in the PDF at hand.

Comment: That been said, you will need the font resource used to display your characters. Your code looks like sample code which has been in PDFBox for ages but was full of assumptions; assumptions which more and more often are not fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks for your quikly reply mkl, yes the font is embedded in the pdf.

Comment: What is it strange is that I can encode it with the encode command of PDFont or loading the UnicodeCMap and decoding the font with the command lookup(byte,int,int); What I'm looking for is the invers function, so to get double byte from string char. I've also tryed the CID function, I get an INT  value, however I don't know how to append that value to a string...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a 1.8'ish version of PDFBox considering the method parameters and return types. I doubt you will find ready-to-use methods to do the Unicode -> CID translation there because those versions do not even have methods for drawing text using multi-byte encodings from scratch. (Actually they only support WinAnsiEncoding, and even that not correctly.) They only support multi-byte encodings for text extraction, i.e. the other direction.

Thus, with your assumed PDFBox version you'd have to use low-level methods to parse those font information yourself

---

Since version 2.0.0 PDFBox does support text drawing with multibyte encodings including font subset creation. Thus, if you can switch to PDFBox version 2, you might be more in luck.

In particular this `PDFont.encode` overload (which now is the only public one) looks right for your task:

```
/**
 * Encodes the given string for use in a PDF content stream.
 *
 * @param text Any Unicode text.
 * @return Array of PDF content stream bytes.
 * @throws IOException If the text could not be encoded.
 */
public final byte[] encode(String text) throws IOException
```

I'm not sure, though, whether this method is properly implemented for fonts read from the PDF, its major use is in combination with fonts generated from external resources.

(Obviously, though, that method cannot help if the font is only embedded as a subset in your PDF and does not contain glyphs for your replacement characters.)

Comment: Hi mkl, I've switched to PDFBox 2.0.1 but unfortunately it doesn't work yet. This time the error is:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+0070 in font RVJLXS+ArialUnicodeMS
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:411)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:351)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:286)
 at jump.Jump.replaceLinksInPdf(Jump.java:77)
 at jump.Jump.main(Jump.java:193)

Comment: I've also installed the fontbox2-0-1.jar even if  Fonts are embedded in the file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ale *No glyph for U+0070 in font RVJLXS+ArialUnicodeMS* clearly says that the replacement text contains characters for which there simply is no glyph in the embedded font. As mentioned above, embedded fonts often are not the full font but only subsets thereof with merely the originally needed glyphs.